# DataTables - Get Values From Modal Form

Tags: jquery, forms, datatables, modal-dialog

I have cobbled together some code and thought I was on the brink of success for the last three days.  I have a large bald spot now, and am turning to you all.  Please note, I am not a programmer and the methods I present to you below may TOTALLY not be the way to achieve the desired outcome.  So I am open to all input!

I am trying to get data that has been pulled from a table and presented in a modal, to send.  That is a short description.

Long description...  I am using DataTables to present a database in table format.  I have added a button to each row in the table that when clicked will pop up a modal form.  This form has a input field and also displays the two cells of the row that was selected. Once the end user puts their name into the input field, I would like for all the data (the name input, and the two fields in the row) to be sent using another on submit function.

The last part of that is were I am killing myself.

When I hit the "Request" button, I only receive the name entered into the `<input>` field.

Here is the modal/form...

```
    <div id="reqModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Song Request</h4>
          </div>

    <form id="myform" action="" method="POST">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p><strong>Name: </strong><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></p>
            <p><strong>Artist: </strong><span id="artist" name="artist"></span></p>
            <p><strong>Title: </strong><span id="title" name="title"></span></p>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button id="btnRequest" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Request</button>
          </div>
    </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the functions...

```
      $('#catalog tbody').on('click', 'button', function() {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
                   table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).select();
                                  
        // craft modal body                                                                 
        $('#artist').html(data.artist);
        $('#title').html(data.title); 
        $('#reqModal').modal('show');                                 
      });


      $("#myform").on('submit' ,(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

        var fdata = new FormData(myform);

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/post/submit.php",
                    data: fdata,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (fdata) {
                    }
            });
     
     }));
```

I have tried creating hidden `input`s but have been unsuccessful adding $artist and $title variables to the `value=` arguments.
I have been trying to plug in `append()` statements to the FormData, but I can not figure out how to carry the var from the `.on('click'` to the `.on('submit'`.

Any help would be appreciated!!  If you need more information I will gladly supply it.  I have tried to plug this scenario into a Fiddle but there I could not get the button on the row to even appear.  So it was useless.

Thanks again for any help!

(I need some rep in order to post pictures...  so...  sorry for no visual aid!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution...

**Form**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Song Request</h4>
      </div>
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><strong>Name: </strong><input id="fname" type="text"></p>
        <p><strong>Artist: </strong><span id="fartist"></span></p>
        <p><strong>Title: </strong><span id="ftitle"</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button id="send" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Request</button>
      </div>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function() {
    myrow = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    table.rows( {page: 'current'} ).deselect();
    table.row( $(this) ).select();
                              
    $('#fartist').html(myrow.artist);
    $('#ftitle').html(myrow.title);                           
    $('#myModal').modal('show');                                 
  });
  

  $('#send').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

      var data = new FormData(myform);
          data.append("name", $('input:text').val());
          data.append("artist", $('#fartist').text());
          data.append("title", $('#ftitle').text());

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "control.php",
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                dataType:'html',
                success: function (data) {
                }
        });

     $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                                        
  });
```